# What is the most performant way to add/remove join table associations for a bi-directional many-to-many association of complex entities?

Tags: performance, hibernate, jpa, query-optimization, associations

Just to be clear, I'm NOT asking how to get things WORKING, but what sort of approach will have the best PERFORMANCE.

The reason I'm so focused on performance is because I'm dealing with 2 very complex and hierarchical entities. To give you a little background, the program is for tracking attendance, so the 2 entities in question are `Location`s (where people attend) and `Reason`s (if people can attend and why). These 2 entities are in a **bi-directional many-to-many relationship** where each entity has multiple thousands of records in the database and are completely independent from each other aside from the mapping table that contains the associations. There can be as few as 1 and infinitely many `Reason`s a person may attend a `Location`, and as few as 1 and infinitely many `Location`s a `Reason` can be used at.

i.e. a `Reason` of '*person is in security group RED*' is used to grant access to locations '*Lab A*', '*Lab B*', and '*Lab C*', resulting in the join table containing 3 entries, each with the '*person is in security group RED*' as the `Reason` side of the relationship and each lab location to associate it to each of the lab `Location` entities. Conversely, `Location` '*Lab A*' may also include other `Reason`s, such as a '*security group BLUE*' and '*training event X*' and will thus have additional records in the join table to those `Reason`s.

Both entities are complex in and of themselves and have many cascading associations of their own. i.e. the `Reason` entity has a 3-tiered cascading relationship structure of its own to maintain, and the `Location` entity has many other associations it's concerned with completely independent from `Reason`s. I stress this to emphasize the performance impact concerns of always pulling in all the entity associations just to update the join table entries.

Most of the time when a `Location` or `Reason` is being updated, it will be completely independent from the associations they have with one another, and so I don't want to worry about the `Location` <--> `Reason` join table for normal operations. However the links between `Location`s and `Reason`s are crucial to the program's primary functions and thus adding and removing these associations are just as crucial. So when it comes to adding/removing these associations, what is the mos performant way of doing so?

I want to avoid the cascade behaviors if I can, because I don't want unrelated changes made to these entities to trigger a complex cascade save. i.e. when `Location` '*X*' changes, I don't want to bring in its many `Reason`s and all their 3-tiered cascaded dependencies when I'm not changing anything related to `Location` '*X*'s reasons at the time. I also don't want to bring in all of `Location` '*X*'s `Reason`s (and their dependencies) just to add/remove an entry in the `Location` <--> `Reason` join table for that `Location` (and conversely the same argument for the `Reason`.)

I was wondering if there was a way to target the `Location` <--> `Reason` join table association directly when I want to add/remove such associations, but otherwise keep it pretty light when dealing with regular operations on the entities.

i.e. I still want to get basic details about the `Reason`s associated with a `Location` when I go to change other details about the `Location`, without cascading the save operation of that `Location` to its `Reason`s (and thus each `Reasons`' downstream associations), and vice versa, and when it comes time add or remove entries to the join table for these entities, I don't want those entities to be saved directly, because then I'd have to worry about all their other data and associations getting updated.

If such a setup isn't possible with hibernate and its nature for tracking entities rather than their associations, which association setup for these entities would have the best performance, knowing that each entity already has many other cascading operations to deal with and most operations on these entities will NOT touch the join table between them at all, and only those targeted add/remove operations will specifically need to update JUST that join table between the location and the reason and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you almost always don't want a real many-to-many association. There will be a time where you want to track additional data like a timestamp for these join tables which is when you would have to rewrite your logic, so I suggest you always try to think about modelling the join table as entity with two many-to-one associations and on the inverse side, one-to-many associations. The entity for the join table has a composite id, consisting of the ids of the many-to-one associations.

This enables you to manage entries manually by doing persist/merge/remove or use update/delete DML queries. This will perform best and the only "downside" is that you might do work upfront that you is possibly not need, because it might in fact be a real many-to-many, although I highly doubt that.

Comment: Well for the last 8 years, it has remained a true many to many association with no other data in the join table... Unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean by a 'real' many-to-many association.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I mean. People often think that they need a many-to-many association but later realize they need additional state and split to two one-to-many associations. It's fine if your many-to-many association is a "real" one, but that doesn't change the fact that being able to manage the individual entries in that join table through an explicit entity has performance advantages. The assumption is you want to stick to the Hibernate ORM model. You could at any time just use SQL to get this done or Blaze-Persistence which supports collection DML statements on top of Hibernate.